# API REST Gui Development like Appery.io

Tags: api, user-interface

I've been using Appery.io to build apps and they have a dead simple way of manipulating Rest API's from other services (Google, and any other API). They allow you to setup the parameters create the response parameters based on the response it receives and to map it accordingly even to map the Arrays to fields. And post works very similarly, a button is mapped to a service and it calls the GET command etc...

Does anyone know of any other such platform or program/extension that makes API this easy and quick?

Thanks